# PostgreSql format jsonb array

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

Can not find a proper query to format jsonb output in postgres
I have a jonb column in a table.

```
Table: Users
id| posts
--------
1 | [{'title': '', 'is_published': '', 'description': '', 'some': 'extra'}, ...]
2 | [{'title': '', 'is_published': '', 'description': '', 'some': 'extra'}, ...]
```

How do I select the posts column to have just certain fields? Something like:

```
id| posts
--------
1 | [{'title':'', 'description': ''}, ...]
2 | [{'title':'', 'description': ''}, ...]
```

Any ideas?

PS: The version of postgres is the latest 12, 13, 14 ...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may considering using [`json_to_record_set`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html) to extract your desired columns for each array element in posts before aggregating the results by the user `id` to obtain the desired elements.

**Query #1**

```
SELECT
    u.id,
    json_agg(
        json_build_object(
            'title',p.title,
            'description',p.description
        )
    ) as posts
FROM
    users u,
    json_to_recordset(u.posts) as p(
          title text,
          is_published text,
          description text,
          some_col text
    )
GROUP BY
    u.id
ORDER BY
    u.id;
```

| id | posts |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"title":"","description":""}] |
| 2 | [{"title":"","description":""}] |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rk4vkkdWLJZs2ygnuKRBx5/0)

or shorter

**Query #2**

```
SELECT
    u.id,
    json_agg(p) as posts
FROM
    users u,
    json_to_recordset(u.posts) as p(
          title text,
          description text
    )
GROUP BY
    u.id
ORDER BY
    u.id;
```

| id | posts |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"title":"","description":""}] |
| 2 | [{"title":"","description":""}] |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rk4vkkdWLJZs2ygnuKRBx5/1)

or

**Query #3**

```
SELECT
    u.id,
    (
        SELECT 
            json_agg(p.*) 
        FROM json_to_recordset(u.posts) as p(
             title text,
             description text
        )
      
    ) as posts
FROM
    users u;
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rk4vkkdWLJZs2ygnuKRBx5/2)

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you a lot! It is exactly what I'm searching for!

Comment: @RomanZaycev Great! Please also mark this answer as the accepted answer so that this will help other Stackoverflow users to identify answers to a similar question they may have.

Comment: Yah. Forgot to make it. Thank you once again!